# Should I use BroadcastReceiver or Service with alarm manager?

Tags: android, android-intent

Should I call my service via broadcast receiver or directly call it using alarm manager. Currently I'm using service directly but some times the alarm is not triggered.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getContext().getApplicationContext(), 1, myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); 

alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: honestly i dont see any difference if your `Intent` points to a `Service` or `BroadcastReceiver` - but you could check [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/) sources and see how they do that

Comment: this one `androidx/work/impl/background/systemalarm/SystemAlarmService.java` in particular - it is executed from `androidx/work/impl/background/systemalarm/Alarms.java`

Answer (score 1):

BroadcastReceiver is not for any type of long-running operations (whether synchronous or asynchronously waiting for some callback). It is simply used for receiving some event (broadcast) then handing off any longer-running action to the appropriate component (i.e. Activity or Service).

IntentService is for a long-running, synchronous operation that is handled on another thread. A (foreground) service allows you to more or less act as an invisible Activity. You can await asynchronous callbacks (i.e. the user dismissing the alarm).

You can use this library i have made.
[service in background and foreground](https://github.com/HossamScott/Background_service) with it you run service and than receive the call with broadcast

with simple code you start call or start your service like this

```
RunService service = new RunService(this);
service.call(5);
```

and do your action inside this method

```
  BroadcastReceiver alarm_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // your logic here
            Log.i("alarm_received", "success");

        }
    };
```

dont forget to register the service and remove the service on destroy same as you see in the documentation.

Comment: But this dosen't answer my question.

Comment: What I'm asking is should I start a service from a BroadcastReciver or directly call it from an alarm manger. Generally most people call the service from BroadcastReciver. I want to know what is the right practice.

Comment: theres no reason at all to call it from broadcast, you should call it directly

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using **Broadcast receiver** and when `onReceive` you can fire service or do anything, also it's useful especially when you need to receive `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` to reschedule your pending alarms because when the device restarted the OS will delete any pending alarms, for more info check this [link](https://medium.com/@valeriachub/classic-chain-alarmmanager-service-broadcastreceiver-with-new-features-from-android-m-and-n-14fc0b4cf0db)

Answer (score -1):

```
namespace Diabetes.Droid
```

{
    [Application]
    public class MainApplication : Application
    {
        ISetAlarm alarmService;
        public static Context AppContext;

```
    public MainApplication()
    {

    }
    public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer) : base(handle, transer)
    {
    }


    public override void OnCreate()
    {

        base.OnCreate();
        AppContext = this.ApplicationContext;
        alarmService = new SetAlarmImplementation();
        alarmService.SetAlarm(13,58,"hello","great work ");
    }



    public void SetAlarm(int hour, int minute, string title, string message)
    {

        AppContext.StartService(new Intent(AppContext, typeof(AppStickyService)));
        Intent myintent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(AppStickyService));
        myintent.PutExtra("message", message);
        myintent.PutExtra("title", title);
        //PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Android.App.Application.Context, 0, myintent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.GetService(AppContext, 0, new Intent(AppContext, typeof(AppStickyService)), 0);

        Java.Util.Date date = new Java.Util.Date();
        Java.Util.Calendar cal = Java.Util.Calendar.Instance;
        cal.TimeInMillis = Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis();
        cal.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.HourOfDay, hour);
        cal.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Minute, minute);
        cal.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Second, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.AlarmService) as AlarmManager;
        alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, cal.TimeInMillis, pintent);
        // alarmManager.Cancel(pintent);

    }





    public void StartService()
    {

        AppContext.StartService(new Intent(AppContext, typeof(AppStickyService)));
        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
        {

            PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.GetService(AppContext, 0, new Intent(AppContext, typeof(AppStickyService)), 0);
            //AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)AppContext.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Service started", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            //alarm.Cancel(pintent);
        }
    }

    public static void StopService()
    {
        AppContext.StopService(new Intent(AppContext, typeof(AppStickyService)));
        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
        {
            // Toast.MakeText(this,"Service started", ToastLength.Long).Show();

            //PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.GetService(AppContext, 0, new Intent(AppContext, typeof(AppStickyService)), 0);
            // AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)AppContext.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
            //alarm.Cancel(pintent);
        }
    }
}
```

This is AlarmImplementation.class

```
public class SetAlarmImplementation : ISetAlarm
{

    public SetAlarmImplementation(){}


    public void SetAlarm(int hour, int minute, string title, string message)
    {


        Intent myintent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
        myintent.PutExtra("message", message);
        myintent.PutExtra("title", title);
        PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Android.App.Application.Context, 0, myintent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        Java.Util.Date date = new Java.Util.Date();
        Java.Util.Calendar cal = Java.Util.Calendar.Instance;
        cal.TimeInMillis = Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis();
        cal.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.HourOfDay, hour);
        cal.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Minute, minute);
        cal.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Second, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.AlarmService) as AlarmManager;
        alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, cal.TimeInMillis, pendingintent);
    }
}
This is BroadcastReceiver.class
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.LowPriority)]
public class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        var message = intent.GetStringExtra("message");
        var title = intent.GetStringExtra("title");

        //Show toast here
        //Toast.MakeText(context, "Hello it's me ", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        var extras = intent.Extras;

        if (extras != null && !extras.IsEmpty)
        {
            NotificationManager manager_ = context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
            var notificationId = extras.GetInt("NotificationIdKey", -1);
            if (notificationId != -1)
            {
                manager_.Cancel(notificationId);
            }
        }

        //Create intent for action 1 (TAKE)
        var actionIntent1 = new Intent();
        actionIntent1.SetAction("ARCHIVE");
        var pIntent1 = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, actionIntent1, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

        //Create intent for action 2 (REPLY)
        var actionIntent2 = new Intent();
        actionIntent2.SetAction("REPLY");
        var pIntent2 = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, actionIntent2, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

        Intent resultIntent = context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(context.PackageName);

        var contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

        var pending = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0,
            resultIntent,
            PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
        //seting an alarm
        MedicationDatabase db = new MedicationDatabase();
        var alarm_list = db.GetAlarmList();
        //Debug.WriteLine(" Time -- : "+ m.ToString());


        // Instantiate the Big Text style:
        Notification.BigTextStyle textStyle = new Notification.BigTextStyle();


        var builder =
            new Notification.Builder(context)
                            .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.tick_notify, "ARCHIVE", pIntent1)
                            .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.cancel_notify, "REPLY", pIntent2)
                            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_launcher)
                            .SetContentTitle("Diabetics Reminder")
                            .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound)
                            .SetStyle(new Notification
                            .BigTextStyle()
                            .SetSummaryText("")
                            .SetBigContentTitle(title)
                            .BigText(message)
         ).SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.All);

        builder.SetContentIntent(pending);

        var notification = builder.Build();


        var manager = NotificationManager.FromContext(context);
        manager.Notify(10010, notification);

    }
}
```

and this is the final service class

```
[Service]
public class AppStickyService : Service
{

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

       // Toast.MakeText(this, "Service started Habiibi", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        //WireAlarm();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Sticky Service - Created");
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Android.Content.Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        SetAlarm(12,39,"Try","Start Service");

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    public override Android.OS.IBinder OnBind(Android.Content.Intent intent)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Sticky Service - Binded");
        //WireAlarm();
        return null;
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Sticky Service - Destroyed");
        base.OnDestroy();
        WireAlarm();
    }
```

Comment: can you elaborate more on the answer?

Comment: this code to be having a sticky service as in when the Application is Idle or sleeping it makes a notification.